# Gazebo loading texture file for custom made model

Tags: gazebo, model

I'm using gazebo and ros for my masterthesis.
Within that I want to use DOPE (deep object pose estimation).

For that I've been tryin to create a gazebo model which is already trained by DOPE.
This works pretty fine so far! But the moment I try to create a second model it doesn't work as planned. I choose a milk carton and a tomato sauce can.
When I open gazebo, insert a path to my models and place the first object (for example the can) it looks as expected. After that I want to place a second object of the other model type (in that case the milk carton) into that simulation. But instead of loading the texture file from the milk carton I get the correct shape but with the texture of my tomato sauce can.

The order doesn't matter. I can start with milk as well. Then I get a can with the texture of my milk carton.

Here are pictures of both cases:
[image]
[image]

The path to the models is:
~/scitos_ws/src/scitos/scitos_description/models/DOPEmilk
~/scitos_ws/src/scitos/scitos_description/models/DOPETomatoSauce

In that folder you can find:

- Folder: "materials"

  - Folder: "scripts"

    - DOPEMilk.material  (or DOPETomatoSauce.material)
  - Folder: "textures"

    - texture_map_flat.png
    - texture_map.png
- Folder: "meshes"

  - textured.obj
  - textured_simple.obj
- model.config
- model.sdf

Here is the output of `gazebo --verbose` while reproducing the issue:

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.11.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.11.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.178.74
[Msg] Loading world file [/usr/share/gazebo-11/worlds/empty.world]
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.178.74
[Wrn] [Event.cc:61] Warning: Deleting a connection right after creation. Make sure to save the ConnectionPtr from a Connect call
```

I have no idea what is going on. Hope you can help me here.

---

Anyone has an idea? I tried to spawn the models from terminal via:

```
rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file scitos_ws/src/scitos/scitos_description/models/DOPEMilk/model.sdf -sdf -x 2 -y 2 -model Milk
```

but the result was the same here...

I also changed the path to the model-files so they aren't using the same directory. Same result...

---

Here is a link to my model files:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OnWViaejV8C35ydyjnYfwMR6cSsAYE4d?usp=sharing

Initially I created that files from that tutorial:
[Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucS_ekzuzMA)

Comment: Without more details it's hard to know what's going on. Please edit your question to share your files and the paths where your putting them and how your launching it, as well as running with `--verbose` and showing the console output with any messages.

Comment: Hi @Tully:
I added some more information. I'm just not sure what's the best way to attach files so I can add them here as well.

Comment: You look like you removed your edits with more helpful errors which are important clues showing that your models have references to the textures that can't be found. You're going to need to show more about what your models are and how your setting your path, and how the models are referencing the textures.

Comment: I removed the warnings, because after tryin a lot I had a small issue I fixed afterwards by my self. But the initial problem stays. I added a link to my files.

Comment: Has anyone an idea? Still struggling...